# Pegar uma propriedade css com jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Teria como eu verificar uma propriedade css com jquery ou js puro?

> Obs: Usar is.(':visible') não é viável no que eu preciso.

Exemplo:

```
var display = $('.test').get('display').val()
        if(display == 'block')
        {
            alert('block');
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, você pode usar `css` para ler as propriedades computadas de um objeto, exemplo: `$('#id').css('background-color');`

Referência: http://api.jquery.com/css/

```js
console.log($('#div1').css('display'));
console.log($('#div2').css('display'));
console.log($('.divClass').css('border'));
```

```css
#div1 {
  display: inline;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}

#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.divClass {
   border: solid 1px #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1' class='divClass'>
<div id='div2' class='divClass'>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente para o que preciso, muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

```
var display = document.querySelector('.sua_classe').style.display;
if(display == 'block')
{
    alert('block');
}
```